# Serializing data with marshmallow if data key is unknown

Tags: python, serialization, marshmallow

I'm trying to serialise data where the data key is not known beforehand. The data would look something like this:

```
{
    "unknown key": ["list", "of", "random", "strings"]
}
```

Is this something that's possible with marshmallow? I can't seem to find anything in the docs about it.

Comment: Why not use `json` for a simple data structure like that? Marshmallow is for complex objects.

Comment: This is just an example, but the actual data structure is much more complex. It's also a design decision that I don't have any control over :)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a method to dynamically generatea  `Schema` class at runtime.

```
from marshmallow import Schema as BaseSchema

class Schema(BaseSchema):
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, fields_dict):
        attrs = fields_dict.copy()
        attrs["Meta"] = type(
            "GeneratedMeta", (getattr(cls, "Meta", object),), {"register": False}
        )
        return type("", (cls,), attrs)
```

Usage:

```
from marshmallow import fields

MySchema = Schema.from_dict({
    "unknown_key": fields.List(fields.Str())
})
```

Update: `Schema.from_dict` is now built-in method in marshmallow 3.0, which will be released soon. See https://stevenloria.com/dynamic-schemas-in-marshmallow/ for usage examples.